# Open File Dialog in node,js (typescript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, typescript, file

I want to open a file dialog in my Node.js typescript project.

I run the project in my cmd so no browser or HTML is involved.

I want to show a box like:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, node js does not provide this functionality.

Comment: @DanStarns Would I be able to achieve this using a `.bat` file or cmd/powershell commands?

Comment: You could use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to spawn a script in another language.

Comment: I tried running a bat file by doing the following:
https://pasteid.fledix.com/701i

Comment: and what happend?...

Comment: It basically ran it correctly, opened a file dialog and when I selected a file and clicked on open, it outputted the chosen file directory. It just didn't work before because I forgot remove a line. Thank you for your assistance however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you, node js does not provide this functionality. However, You could use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to spawn a script in another language.